# How do I setup Git on my Linux server?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, server

I have a remote linux server that I SSH into.  Git is installed on both my local machine and on my remote server.

I was thinking of setting up a bare repo on the linux server and pushing changes from a working repo on my local machine.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: Maybe. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Or better [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I don't understand what guideline I'm not following - is this too complex a question?

Comment: @cadegalt: You are asking for an opinion. Please remember that SO is a Q/A forum that provides empirically determined answers to well formed questions. Are you asking if there is a 'best practice' for hosting a private git environment?

Comment: This question is off topic for this site, is much too broad, is looking for an opinion, and does not demonstrate what you have tried so far or what documentation you have consulted and where you are encountering difficulties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what a bare git repository is intended for.  If you are not actually editing the files on the server this is what you should use.

Here is a [good link](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) from saintsjd.com.

There is a very common git pattern in which you push to a bare repo, and that bare repo has a hook ( post-receive ) which then checks out to a full repo.

This would be a good starting point.